# How To Gracefully Shutdown A Nestjs Application

Tags: typescript, backend, nestjs, nest

I am handling `unhandledPromiseRejections` and i want shutdown the app gracefully when that happens and also close the listening port and exit process ....

P.S i have read the life-cycle section in the docs ... **NOT HELPFUL**

see code in `main.ts` below ---- Doesn't work ... the process is not terminated on console

the official docs didn't state any central way to shutdown the application .. it only stated how to  use the lifecycle methods in modules but that is not what i want for now

```js
/**
 * @desc - Starts the application, assembly point of all the modules
 */
async function bootstrap() {
  //application execution port

  //logger instance  - No dependency injection
  const logger = new LogService();

  process.on('uncaughtException', (err: Error) => {
    logger.log('❌❌❌ ➡ ⬇⬇⬇ An Error occurred -> UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION ERROR ⬇⬇⬇');

    const error = {
      name: err.name,
      message: err.message,
      stack: err.stack,
    };

    // log error to console
    logger.error(err.message, error.stack);

    // send exception error to log file
    logger.exception(error);

    setTimeout(() => {
      process.exit(1);
    }, 100);
  });

  //Nest application artifect creation
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    logger,
  });

  // Starts listening for shutdown hooks
  app.enableShutdownHooks();

  //fetching config service to get env variables
  const config_service = app.get(ConfigService);

  const HOST: string = config_service.get<string>(CONFIG.HOST);

  const PORT: number = config_service.get<number>(CONFIG.PORT);

  //injecting logger module into application
  // app.useLogger(app.get(WINSTON_MODULE_NEST_PROVIDER));

  //applying global pipe to application
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe(VALIDATION_RULE));

  //using global filters - exception handling
  app.useGlobalFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter());

  await app.listen(PORT);

  //log messages on application init
  logger.log(`ℹℹℹ LISTENING TO SERVER ${HOST}:${PORT} ℹℹℹ`);

  process.on('unhandledRejection', async (err: Error) => {
    logger.log(
      '❌❌❌ ➡ ⬇⬇⬇ An Error occured -> UNHANDLED REJECTION ERROR ⬇⬇⬇',
    );

    const error = {
      name: err.name,
      message: err.message,
      stack: err.stack,
    };

    // log error to console
    logger.error(error.message, error.stack);

    // send error to log file
    logger.rejection(error);

    //close application
    await app.close();

    //exit application
    process.exit(1);
  });
}

//run
bootstrap();
```

Comment: Did you try just adding a `.catch()` following the call to bootstrap?